# Why projection map $π: E\longrightarrow M$ in a vector bundle is a homotopy equivalence.

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles

Suppose $(E, M, π)$ is a vector bundle. I want to show that projection map

$π: E\longrightarrow M$ is a homotopy equivalence. I know for every open set
$U$ in $M$ we have a diffeomorphism (local trivialization)
$$φ \colonπ^{-1} (U) \longrightarrow M×R^n .$$
I know that every diffeomorphism is a homeomorphism and so is a homotopy equivalence. But I don't
know how to show $π: E\longrightarrow M$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Hint: prove that the zero section is a homotopy inverse for the projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s$ be the zero section, we have $\pi\circ s= Id_M$.

Let $x\in M$, $v\in E_x$, the map $\pi_t(v)=tv$ is well defined $\pi_1=Id_M$,$s\circ \pi=\pi_0$. This is equivalent to saying that $s\circ \pi$ is homotopic to $Id_M$.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I think SoP Is homotopic to IdE, not IdM. And we have to show that SoP is homotopic to IdE , to complete the proof.Is my argument correct?